# Android - how to get installed package in JNI C code

Tags: android, java-native-interface, package

I have a requirement to implement an equivalent of following java code in JNI C on android:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
for(PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
 ...
}
```

My question is how to get installed packages in JNI C. Is it even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to call `PacakgeManager` via JNI. There is no "C interface", you have to go through the system service. Installing a package does quite a few things, so just copying the APK to the right place is not enough.

Comment: Agreed. I checked the PackageManager code of AOSP and it's pure java. No way to do it in JNI C.